# Python - Using a Kronecker Delta with ODEINT

Tags: python, odeint, delta

I'm trying to plot the output from an ODE using a Kronecker delta function which should only become 'active' at a specific time = t1.
This should give a sawtooth like response where the initial value decays down exponentially until t=t1 where it rises again instantly before decaying down once again.
However, when I plot this it looks like the solver is seeing the Kronecker delta function as zero for all time t. Is there anyway to do this in Python?

```
from scipy import KroneckerDelta
import scipy.integrate as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def dy_dt(y,t):

    dy_dt = 500*KroneckerDelta(t,t1) - 2y

return dy_dt

t1 = 4
y0 = 500
t = np.arrange(0,10,0.1)

y = sp.odeint(dy_dt,y0,t)

plt.plot(t,y)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the problem could be internal rounding errors, because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a python `float`. I would try

```
import math

def dy_dt(y,t): 
    if math.isclose(t, t1):
        return 500 - 2*y
    else:
        return -2y
```

Also the documentation of `odeint` suggests using the `args` parameter instead of global variables to give your derivative function access to additional arguments and replacing `np.arange` by `np.linspace`:

```
import scipy.integrate as sp 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
import math

def dy_dt(y, t, t1): 
    if math.isclose(t, t1):
        return 500 - 2*y
    else:
        return -2*y

t1 = 4 
y0 = 500 
t = np.linspace(0, 10, num=101) 
y = sp.odeint(dy_dt, y0, t, args=(t1,)) 
plt.plot(t, y)
```

I did not test the code so tell me if there is anything wrong with it.

---

**EDIT:**

When testing my code I took a look at the `t` values for which `dy_dt` is evaluated. I noticed that `odeint` does not only use the `t` values that where specified, but alters them slightly:

```
...
3.6636447422787928
3.743098503914526
3.822552265550259
3.902006027185992
3.991829287543431
4.08165254790087
4.171475808258308
...
```

Now using my method, we get

```
math.isclose(3.991829287543431, 4) # False
```

because the default tolerance is set to a relative error of at most 10^(-9), so the `odeint` function "misses" the bump of the derivative at 4. Luckily, we can fix that by specifying a higher error threshold:

```
def dy_dt(y, t, t1): 
    if math.isclose(t, t1, abs_tol=0.01):
        return 500 - 2*y
    else:
        return -2*y
```

Now `dy_dt` is very high for all values between 3.99 and 4.01. It is possible to make this range smaller if the `num` argument of `linspace` is increased.

---

**TL;DR**

Your problem is not a problem of python but a problem of numerically solving an differential equation: You need to alter your derivative for an interval of sufficient length, otherwise the solver will likely miss the interesting spot. A kronecker delta does not work with numeric approaches to solving ODEs.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into this! Very in depth answer :)

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, you can accept it to give me some reputation. Learn more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a simple Kronecker delta using time, you can run the ode in pieces like so:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def dy_dt(y,t):
    return -2*y

t_delta = 4
tend = 10
y0 = [500]

t1 = np.linspace(0,t_delta,50)
y1 = odeint(dy_dt,y0,t1)

y0 = y1[-1] + 500  # execute Kronecker delta
t2 = np.linspace(t_delta,tend,50)
y2 = odeint(dy_dt,y0,t2)

t = np.append(t1, t2)
y = np.append(y1, y2)
plt.plot(t,y)
```

Another option for complicated situations is to the `events` functionality of [solve_ivp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html).